# load image from url UIWEBVIEW +iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am trying to display the image in `UIWebView` and added uiwebiview into the uiscrollview as i wanna give the page controller effect:-

```
UIWebView *webview_obj=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xcorrd,0,200,320)];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src='%@' width='100%' height='100%'></body></html>",imageStr];
[webview_obj loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
webview_obj.scalesPageToFit=YES;
[scroll_views addSubview:webview_obj];
```

My problem is :-
When i try to load the image of sizd 200X320. the image come in perfect size.but some white portion(approximate 30-40pixel) will added on the bottom and side of the webview.
and automatically the content size get increase and give the scroll.

I am uploading the screenshot for the output i am getting:-

[image]

Black potion in the webview part.and white is somehting which get automatically added to the image..
the size of the image i am using is :- 200 :- with and 320 :- height
Thanks & Regards
shweta

Comment: Hi why do you need an UIWebView to show image by the way? You can use an UIImageView component, I think you are adding in scrollview, is your scrollview on correct frame? You can check whether webview is showing correct image or, not by trying to scroll webview down, or, right.. A webview has a background it will appear and will give you idea that it is actually happening or, not. As per my code for css style it should not have margins, and padding.. It must be something else.. All the best

Answer (score 3):

Added `CSS STYLE` in the `HEAD` tag..

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>body{padding:0; margin:0;}</style></head><body><img src='%@' width='100%' height='100%'></body></html>",imageStr];
```

Comment: iPhonic I had edited my question and uploaded the screenhot please have a look once.